# Jenkins pass variable into groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Hi I need to pass a variable from select into the groovy script and I haven't a clue how to do it in variable bindings, anyone has an idea how to do it?

I tried with:

> version=version
>
> version=$version
>
> version=${version}
>
> version="${version}"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use ${ ... } Notation you should enclose it double quotes, i.e.:

```
versionVar = "${version}"
```

The other think that keeps bothering me is that you are using the same variable name. I haven't tried but I think that using the same name you could are trying to use the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the 'version' variable came from?
If you are trying to use Environment variables, then you should try like,

```
version = env.version
```